# WebHooks Registration "Bad Request" Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webhooks

I am trying to register webhook to my Asp.net web Api application via ajax and get **bad request (jquery)** although everything seems perfect.

```
 function subscribe() {
        var obj = {
            WebHookUri: "http://localhost:15975/api/Tempo",
            Secret: "12345678901234567890123456789012",
            Description: "Chill"
        };
   var dsf=  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/webhooks/registrations",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status) { alert(status); },
        failure: function(errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I found from documentation and sample code.
`Bad Request(400)` state occurs when any of the following happens;

- `obj`is null
- `WebHookUri` property of `obj`is a `Get` callback uri so it should be valid and responsive
- URI should rertrn `[echo]` [query parameter](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/pull/47/commits/f8f8b34d8f03848baede1cc81f5bafa6a1b0d8d6)